# Want to overlay multiple plots on top of each other

Tags: animate

I've created multiple `.pdf` files with animations using the animation package in R. For example, I have these two plots:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\animategraphics[controls,width=.8\linewidth]{20}{Rplot8_7}{}{}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\animategraphics[controls,width=.8\linewidth]{20}{Rplot8_6}{}{}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here are the .pdf files:

[Plot A](http://www.docdroid.net/w27r/rplot8-5.pdf.html)

[Plot B](http://www.docdroid.net/vyln/rplot8-6.pdf.html)

I want to reduce the number of plots to one. So I would like to literally overlay one on top of the other and be able to navigate between these plots with a tab PLUS the ability to navigate between each plot's animations, which is what I have already. So I guess the idea is to have animation on two dimensions: one for the plots, and the other for each plot's animations. To make my point even more clear, here is a crudely drawn MS paint image:

[image: Two dimensional animation]

Of course, the final product would just look like one plot with two tabs to navigate between each animation. Is there a way to do this in LaTeX? I've looked at the animate package documentation and couldn't find much. If not, I will look for further options. Of course, any ideas to overcome this is appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: Some code I tried to do with more than 2 plots:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}[2015/03/11]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{fixocgx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}\centering
\makebox[0pt][l]{%
\begin{ocg}{A}{A}{1}%
  \animategraphics[controls,width=.8\linewidth]{20}{Rplot8_5}{}{}%
\end{ocg}%
}%
\begin{ocg}{B}{B}{0}%
  \animategraphics[controls,width=.8\linewidth]{20}{Rplot8_6}{}{}%
\end{ocg}
\begin{ocg}{C}{C}{0}%
  \animategraphics[controls,width=.8\linewidth]{20}{Rplot8_7}{}{}%
\end{ocg}

\actionsocg{A B C}{A}{B C}{\fbox{Plot A}}
\actionsocg{A B C}{B}{A C}{\fbox{Plot B}}
\actionsocg{A B C}{C}{A B}{\fbox{Plot C}}
\caption{Two animations on different layers}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But I get something funky:

[image]

Is there a way to get the plots all in one spot instead of putting one on top of the other when space runs out?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Take a look at section 8.1 in the documentation for the animate package.  Find using http://texdoc.net/ with a search for animate.

Comment: @SoundsofSilence Thanks, I edited the post and sorry for not doing a MWE on my first post. I will keep it in mind for future posts!

Comment: @R.Schumacher I am currently looking at the documentation and playing with the code to see if I can make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animations can be put on PDF Layers using the `ocgx` and `fixocgx` packages. Package `animate` version `2015/03/11` is required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}[2015/03/11]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ocgx}
\usepackage{fixocgx}[2015/03/11]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}\centering
\makebox[0pt][l]{%
\begin{ocg}{A}{A}{1}%
  \animategraphics[controls,width=.8\linewidth]{20}{Rplot8_5}{}{}%
\end{ocg}%
}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{%
\begin{ocg}{B}{B}{0}%
  \animategraphics[controls,width=.8\linewidth]{20}{Rplot8_6}{}{}%
\end{ocg}%
}%
\begin{ocg}{C}{C}{0}%
  \animategraphics[controls,width=.8\linewidth]{20}{Rplot8_7}{}{}%
\end{ocg}

\actionsocg{}{A}{B C}{\fbox{Plot A}}
\actionsocg{}{B}{A C}{\fbox{Plot B}}
\actionsocg{}{C}{A B}{\fbox{Plot C}}
\caption{Three animations on different layers}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Every ocg environment, except the last one, must be placed into a zero-width `\makebox`. Also, line endings in between must be protected with '%' to prevent spurious space from being inserted. Then, all animated plots are placed on top of each other.

Comment: This works, but I am having trouble when I try to do this for more than two plots. The trouble is that the third plot is placed below the other two plots. I edited my first post for your convenience. Is there a way around this? And I apologize but I cannot put up a third .pdf file since my reputation is too low. :(

Comment: You will have to put every `ocg` environment into a zero-width `\makebox` except the last one. And make sure that all line endings in between are protected with '`%`' to prevent spurious space from being inserted.