# Sequence of Images

Tags: graphics, animations, animate, sequence

I would as a teacher I would like to add to my pdf (usually it is an article) a sequence of images for some geometry proofs.
For example, it would be nice to have something like:

1. Draw the triangle ABC
2. Draw the bisector of A
3. Draw the height of AB passing through C
4. ...

For each step, I would like to have a corresponding image but I don't want to display all of them, it would be nice to have something like

[image]

With 2 buttons and a place to display the image,
Is it possible?

Thank you so much.
Best regards

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, maybe you can clarify? You mention that this is for a teaching setting, and that you already have an (article) pdf. Do you want to put the images somewhere in or on top of the existing article? Or do you want to make a separate set of slides (similar to Powerpoint) to illustrate the article? Is this for students to study at home, or do you present this in class (with full control over which viewer you use)? Are the arrows necessary, or would just clicking/pressing arrow keys (like in Powerpoint) be acceptable?

Comment: Is using the LaTeX beamer class an option for you? In that case you can achieve the "switching of images" by different overlays.

Comment: If it take up the whole page, not a problem.  Otherwise, you are talking eforms and javascript.

Comment: @Marijn I use it both in class and I give the pdf to my students so that they can study, I could do that easily by creating different slides in breamer but maybe there is an alternative in the article document

Comment: Maybe something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235770/want-to-overlay-multiple-plots-on-top-of-each-other?

Comment: @Matteo, if you perceive your previous/next „buttons“ as page buttons, any pdf viewer already provides it: just prepare 6 consecutive pages … and that‘s animation from scratch. It probably will also work fine if you have, say, 2 developing images per page.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sketch how you can achieve something similar using beamer:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{}
        \centering
        \only<1>{
            This is the first step:\\[1em]
            
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
        }
        \only<2>{
            This is the second step:\\[1em]
            
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
        }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is the resulting PDF (2 pages):

[image]

Beamer shows some control for switching to the next slide (see the bottom right). This might work for you. Otherwise, you still could use hyperlinks to create your own navigation buttons.

Comment: Ok, is this possible to add it in an article page?

Comment: Thank you for your solution

Comment: I'm afraid, this only works in beamer...

Comment: Oh, and if this has solved your problem then it would be helpful for others if you mark this as "solution".